# How can I locally access the DOM of a website?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-domain

At the moment, I am working for a courier/delivery company in an admin role. One of the tasks required of us is to take a long list of tracking numbers, manually put them into a parcel tracking website (hosted on the companies intranet), find certain information about each parcel from the tracking, and write it down.

This is rather repetitive and monotonous, so I decided to write a script that does this for you. So far, I've created the (javascript) code to get the necessary information. However, at the moment, you must copy and paste this script into the F12 developer tools in order to use it (and this must be done every time you enter a new tracking number).

What I now wish to do is create a local program which effectively adds my javascript to the tracking page for each parcel, gets the result returned by the javascript, then continues to do the same for the next parcel, and so on.

So, how can I automate this process of using my javascript to evaluate each parcel on the tracking website?

Comment: So where is this script you have? Would it be possible for you to setup some form of example that will give people something to work with...

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a [*bookmarklet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). This is a bookmark which starts with the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol and consists of URI-encoded JavaScript code. When you click the bookmark in the bookmarks bar, the code runs on the page and can manipulate that page.

Alternately, you can install GreaseMonkey, TamperMonkey, or other similar extensions to run JavaScript on a web page automatically when you visit it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NightmareJS - browser automation library. You can interact with a page, preload your scripts etc. There are also many alternatives but i prefer this framework because of full JS stack.
[Github link](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare)